# how to write ESQL code for a Soap Request?

Tags: soap, websphere, messagebroker, extended-sql

I want `ESQL` code for the xml soap request,to use for soap request node in `IIB`.
this is simple soap request I need to convert to `ESQL` (extended sql).

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:emp="http://tempuri.org/employees_ms">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <emp:ReqDetails xmlns:emp="http://tempuri.org/employees_ms">
         <emp:EMP_ID>EJD3</emp:EMP_ID>
         <emp:SALARY_INC>200</emp:SALARY_INC>
      </emp:ReqDetails>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Then come back and [edit] your question. Post the code of what you've tried as a [mcve]. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?

Comment: new to here. i will format the question in a proper way,thank you for your advise,anyway i figured out myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Introduction

i found answer of my question.the below ESQL code is the answer of the above Soap request(xml) ,the soap request used to invoke external web service form a message flow.

```
    DECLARE ns1 NAMESPACE 'http://tempuri.org/employees_ms';
    DECLARE soapenv NAMESPACE 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
    SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.soapenv:Envelope.(XMLNSC.NamespaceDecl)xmlns:ns1 = ns1;
    SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.soapenv:Envelope.(XMLNSC.NamespaceDecl)xmlns:soapenv = soapenv;
    SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.soapenv:Envelope.soapenv:Body.ns1:ReqDetails.ns1:EMP_ID='EJD2';
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.soapenv:Envelope.soapenv:Body.ns1:ReqDetails.ns1:SALARY_INC =200;
```

### Explanation

this code inside **compute node** .the **compute nod**e lies before the **SOAPRequest node** .so the compute node in the message flow create soap request to a **SOAPRequest Node**. so as per WSDL for external soap web service first we need to create the name spaces as per the WSDL.i will explain the ESQL code structure below

1. Define Namespaces 
    first two lines which starts with 'DECLARE'.
2. Declare the namespaces
    third and fourth lines which Declare the namespaces in Output Root.
3. Defining the Soap body 
    rest of the code is the main part which define the body of the soap request.i have 
    skipped the header in it because this is meant to test a web service
   *Note:*for more info look the documentation of  ESQL namespace declaration and SOAP
      request